# How to stop playing sound by ondestory method?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I have new code to stop play sound when click on mute button in mobile or click back button "out from app" . I did my code below but the sound still playing although I haven't any errors.

```
public class x extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mp;
private String TAG;
Context mContext;
private IntentListener listener = new IntentListener();
WebAppInterface wb= new WebAppInterface(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ramadan);

    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    // Intiate interface

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart(); 
}

@Override 
protected void onResume() {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    registerReceiver(listener, intentFilter);

    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (wb != null) {
        wb.stop();

    }
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    wb.pause();
    unregisterReceiver(listener);
}

@Override

public void onDestroy(){
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    if (intentFilter !=null){
    Log.v("SERVICE","Service killed");
    wb.stop();
}
    super.onDestroy();  
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{ 
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
{ 
   mp= MediaPlayer.create(Ramadan.this,R.raw.sound); 

if(mp.isPlaying()) 
{
    mp.stop();
    return true; 
}

} 
else return false;


}
}
```

WebAppInterface class

```
public class WebAppInterface    {
     Context mContext;
 private MediaPlayer mp;

WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}
public void pause( ) {

    mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
    if(mp!=null)
    {
          mp.pause();}
    }

public void stop( ) {
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
    if(mp!=null)
    {
        mp.stop();
          mp.release();
    }
        }

  @JavascriptInterface
public void playsound(String value ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.sound);
  mp.start();
    }
    else 
    {  mp.stop();}
}
```

intent listener class

```
public class IntentListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //here code do be executed on when intent comes
    }
}
```

manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.x.y"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: a bit more explanation of your issue would be good. Currently you just throw code at us and say it didn't stop... where and when should it stop and when not?

Comment: it must stop when press lock mobile button and this mute the sound also when i press back button "out" from mobile

Comment: I dont understand: You want to stop playing when you push back button outside the application -with the app playing in background- or when you 'close' the app?

Comment: _I_ _dont_ _understand:_ _You_ _want_ _to_ _stop_ _playing_ _when_ _you_ _push_ _back_ _button_ _outside_ _the_ _application_ _-with_ _the_ _app_ _playing_ _in_ _background-?_

Sorry I edited: this was what you want, no? I think you can't, you should make a notification to get back to app and close it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `onDestroy()` code as below:

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(x.this,R.raw.sound);
    if(mp.isPlaying())
    {
      mp.stop();
      mp.release();
    }
   }
```

Comment: onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called... also creating a new MediaPlayer will probably result in unclear behavior as you only stop/release the newly created..

Comment: Sorry. I missed a line there. Please see my edited answer. Add `super.onDestroy()`. Instead of using `onDestroy`, better place in `onStop()` and `onPause()` methods.

Comment: the error disappeared but the sound still playing what did y mean with " better place in onStop() and onPause() methods"

Comment: Instead of stopping `Mediaplayer` in `onDestroy()`, Place it in `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods because `onDestroy()` will never be called, but only when u kill the application. First check in `onPause()`. Just replace `onDestroy` with `onPause` in above code.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  mp= MediaPlayer.create(Ramadan.this,R.raw.sound);
     if(mp.isPlaying())
     {
       mp.stop();
       mp.release();
     }
 }

Comment: Remove `mp.release()` and check in onPause().

Comment: it worked but when rotate or puss back mobile button error " the application stopped .." happened

Comment: Ok. That can also be resolved. Place this line for that activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file: `android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Comment: For Device Back button press, add this code: `@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(x.this,R.raw.sound);
    if(mp.isPlaying())
    {
      mp.stop();
      mp.release();
    }
  } else
   return;

 }`

Comment: i had this error at onkeydown This method must return a result of type boolean , also i added return true

Comment: ok forgot to add return type. Please add this: `@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { mp= MediaPlayer.create(x.this,R.raw.sound); if(mp.isPlaying()) { mp.stop(); return true; } } else return; }`

Comment: Please add this: `@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { mp= MediaPlayer.create(x.this,R.raw.sound); if(mp.isPlaying()) { mp.stop(); return true; } } else return false; }`

Comment: the same error here " else return ; " also rotate have the error " application stopped ..."

Comment: Please see the above comment. I have modified the code. Please place  this code: `@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { mp= MediaPlayer.create(x.this,R.raw.sound); if(mp.isPlaying()) { mp.stop(); return true; } } else return false; }`

Comment: i added your method at the question but the error still happened please check the edits

Comment: OMG!!! I cant help u buddy... Where you have added `onKeyDown()`?? Please add that in Class which extends Activity. Really Really frustrating with your poor coding Skills. I am helping u since last 2 hours and you dont know what i am telling and what u r doing....

Comment: @Avadhani  i already added it at extends Activity , i added it here by wrong ,  but the back disabled and the rotate have the same error till now

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are creating a new MediaPlayer on your `stop()` and `pause()` methods. As @WarrenFaith said you only stop or pause a newly created MediaPlayer so the playeing one (your mp attribute) remains playing in background.

In my opinion you should try by deleting those `Mediaplayer.create` calls